# What are phi features?

Tags: syntax, terminology

How are some interpretable and some not? Where do they come from? There is a claim that in some languages, like Hebrew, finite T can have either a 'full' set or a partial set - but how is that determined?

Comment: I assume you have at least looked it up in Adger's textbook?

Comment: You assume incorrectly, I know of the book but have no access to it for the next few days. Pretty much everywhere I've looked has pointed to it, so that is a problem.

Comment: Don't worry about it. There'll be many versions already and soon anyone using the term will have their own sense of it. Most people won't ever have heard of it anyway; like apostrophe's and non-terminals, it's indetectable except by people who got their PhDs in the right place at the right time.

Comment: @JohnLawlerinexile. Out of curiosity: why is it called "phi"? I am interested in the etymology.

Comment: I don't really know. It's a greek letter, and that falutes higher than anything descriptive. For the same reason, many generativists call what were originally called "Thematic roles" (and even more originally "cases") "Theta roles", because theta is the letter that starts the word _themata_ in Greek. It must be very very scientific because it's got a greek letter. Anytime a linguist uses a question begging term like "phi" or "theta" you're allowed to believe they're begging a question. Unless they can explain it in clear terms. Which they usually can't.

Comment: When I type the title of your question in Google, I get rather helpful explanations in the first links. Just saying.